# Run test methode in phpunit Testsuite

Tags: php, phpunit, test-suite

I would like to create a testsuite which will run a list of test methods.
I just found a way to run the whole file.
Is there a way to just run a specific methode?
like so:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="src/autoload.php">
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="money">
      <file>tests/IntlFormatterTest.php::test1</file>
      <file>tests/IntlFormatterTest.php::test5</file>
      <file>tests/CurrencyTest.php::test7</file>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible (and not desirable) to configure using the XML configuration file.

What you want is to use `--filter` to dynamically select the tests to execute.

Comment: hey, thank you for your fast response. I used
--filter=(test1234|test2334|test2337) as an alternative. 
This works fine but does not look that nice.
But still works as needed